# 'libxml/xmlstring.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

`CocoaPods`を使用して`ShareKit`をプロジェクトに追加したのですが、`'libxml/xmlstring.h' file not found`というエラーが出て困っています。`Build Settings`の`Header Search Paths`にも`"$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2"`は追加されています。手当たり次第調べてやってみたのですが、うまくいきません。どうすればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: `libxml/xmlstring.h` をインクルードorインポートする部分を `libxml2/xmlstring.h` に変更する(`libxml`->`libxml2`)必要があるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。#import <libxml/xmlstring.h> を #import <libxml2/xmlstring.h> に変更したのですが、「libxml2/xmlstring.h' file not found」というエラーが出てしまいました。。。

Comment: なるほど。。念の為確認ですが、`$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2/xmlstring.h` ファイルは存在するファイルですよね？

Comment: すみません、xmlstring.hがどこに存在するかわかってないです。。。探してみたのですが。。。

Comment: すみません、勘違いをしていました。Header Search Paths にある `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2` を `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/` に変更するとどうなりますでしょうか？

Comment: $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/に変更してみたのですが、エラー内容などに変化はありませんでした。

Comment: 了解です。`xmlstring.h` などが別の場所にインストールされている可能性が高いですね。。。

Comment: 別の場所にインストールですか。。。
了解です。ライブラリの再インストールしてみたいと思います。

Comment: ところで、libxml2.dylib は追加されていますよね？

Comment: はい、インストールされています。

Comment: はい、それでは私のコメントは全て忘れて下さい。。。また何か分かりましたらコメントします。

Comment: すみません、協力して下さり誠に感謝しています。

Comment: [$(SRCROOT) や $(BUILD_DIR) 等の Xcode で使用しているマクロの置換内容の一覧を調べる方法](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/shu223/20120804/1344155002) で `$(SDKROOT)` が実際どの場所か確認することができます。その場所から `/usr/include/libxml2/xmlstring.h` と辿っていってファイルがあるかないか確認してみてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。リンク先に書いてある「env」コマンドはプロジェクトのフォルダ内で使用すればよろしいのでしょうか？しかしenv.txtは出力されたものの、$(SDKROOT)に関する情報が見当たりません。。。SDKROOTの場所は「SDKROOT = 〜」としてファイルに出力されるのでしょうか？

Comment: 自分の環境ではシミュレータ環境で実行した場合 `SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode6.x.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk` の行が存在します。参考までに env.txt の全文を貼り付けております。https://gist.github.com/KAMEDAkyosuke/2bbd2e6d151ea1d182ef

Comment: SDKROOTの場所までたどり着くことができました！ありがとうございます。xmlstring.hファイルを確認しに行くと「/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/」にxmlstring.hファイルがありました。なので、Header Search Paths に「"$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2/libxml"」と入れてみたのですが、それでも「libxml/xmlstring.h file not found」のエラーが出てしまいました。。。

Comment: 「Header Search Paths に「"$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2/libxml"」と入れてみたのですが」とありますが、Header Search Paths に入れるべき値は `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2` が正しいです。ただ、最初はそういう状態だったのでエラーが発生するのは不可解ですね。`$(SDKROOT)` ではなく実際の値を入力した場合はどうなるでしょうか？自分の環境では `/Applications/Xcode6.x.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator‌​.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/usr/include/libxml‌​2` を入力することとなります。（シミュレータと本番ではパスが違うので注意してください。）

Comment: 実際の値を入力してみたのですが、やはり同じエラーが出てしまいます。。。